# React Hooks FileReader. Warning: unstable_flushDiscreteUpdates: Cannot flush updates when React is already rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, filereader, use-effect

I try to use **FileReader** on **FileWidgetDropzone** after the file is selected.

I use a function with **onLoadCallback**:

```
const readFile = (file: any, onLoadCallback: any) => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = onLoadCallback;
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  };
```

I use State to store result data (fileMetadata) from **onLoadCallback** function:

```
 const [loadedFileReader, setLoadFileReader] = useState(false);  
 const [fileMetadata, setFileMetadata] = useState<IFileMetadata>(
    new FileMetadataValues()
  );
 const [files, setFiles] = useState<any[]>([]);
```

The function that uses **readFile** and update state inside a **onLoadCallback**:

```
const getFileExif = (file: any) => {   
    setLoadFileReader(true);
    readFile(file, function(e: any) {     
      const data = ... e.target.result;
      if (data) {
        var model = new FileMetadataValues();
        ...
          setFileMetadata(model);
          setLoadFileReader(false);
        }
      }
    });    
  };
```

**Use Effect** to get additional file data

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (files.length >0 && !loadedFileReader) {    
      getFileExif(files[0]);  
      return () => {
        files.forEach(file => URL.revokeObjectURL(file.preview));
      };    
    }
  }, [files]);


 return (
        <div>
          <FileWidgetDropzone
...
```

This component was rerendered each time then the state change is called from getFileExif function (total 4 times).

When I put **debugger;** before return (... I get an error coon console log: Warning - index.js:1 **Warning: unstable_flushDiscreteUpdates: Cannot flush updates when React is already rendering.**

Please help to develop a more efficient solution for this example.

Answer (score 0):

A solution was found when use React Dropzone. I use Promises.

Parent component:

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState<any[]>([]);
const [filesMetadata, setFilesMetadata] = useState<any[]>([]);
```

Child component:

```
 const getFilesMetadata = (acceptedFiles: object[]) => {
    const files = [...acceptedFiles];
    parseMeta(files);
  };

 files.forEach((file: any) => {
      let promise = new Promise(resolve => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onabort = () => console.log("file reading was aborted");
        reader.onerror = () => console.log("file reading has failed");
        reader.onload = () => {
        ...
        resolve(model);
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      });
      promises.push(promise);
    });
    Promise.all(promises).then((data) => {    
      setFilesMetadata(
        data.map((fileMeta: FileMetadataValues) =>
          Object.assign(fileMeta, fileMeta)
        )
      );
    });

 const onDrop = useCallback(
    acceptedFiles => {
      setFiles(
        acceptedFiles.map((file: object) =>
          ...
        )
      );      
      getFilesMetadata(acceptedFiles);      
    },
    [setFiles, getFilesMetadata]
  );

  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({ onDrop });
```